# why is my boolean not working in my constructor and overload constructor

Tags: c++, class, boolean

I am working on a school project where we have to use a class, a constructor, and an overload constructor to write out this output:

```
Year 2020:
Building 1 has 10 floors, 20 apartments, and is 100% occupied. Full? true
Building 2 has 30 floors, 30 apartments, and is 75% occupied. Full? false
Many years pass.
Year 2043:
Building 1 has 10 floors, 20 apartments, and is 0% occupied. Full? false
Building 2 has 30 floors, 30 apartments, and is 100% occupied. Full? true
Looks like people prefer taller buildings.
```

Now I have everything working except for my boolean, which is used to determine if the building is fully occupied. I am not sure what the problem is, I have used numerical values and wrote out `false` and `true` for my `if` loop that when we ran if it is true then my string value will be assigned the value of `true` and print true later on and if false then it will be assigned `false` and print later on.

```
  myBuilding1.setfullyOccupied(1);
  myBuilding2.setfullyOccupied(0);
  string fullOccupied;
  if (bool fullyOccupied = 0) {
    fullOccupied = "false";
  } else if (bool fullyOccupied = 1) {
    fullOccupied = "true";
  }

  cout << "Year 2020: " << endl;
  cout << "Building 1 has " << myBuilding1.getStories() << " floors, "
       << myBuilding1.getApartments() << " apartments, and it " << percento
       << "% occupied. Full? "
       << /*myBuilding1.getfullyOccupied()*/ fullOccupied << endl;
  cout << "Building 2 has " << myBuilding2.getStories() << " floors, "
       << myBuilding2.getApartments() << " apartments, and it " << percentt
       << "% occupied. Full? "
       << /*myBuilding2.getfullyOccupied()*/ fullOccupied << endl;

  cout << "\nMany years pass."
       << "\n\nYear 2043: " << endl;
  myBuilding1.setOccupancy(0.0);
  myBuilding2.setOccupancy(1.0);
  myBuilding1.setfullyOccupied("false");
  myBuilding2.setfullyOccupied("true");

  if (bool fullyOccupied = "false") {
    fullOccupied = "false";
  } else if (bool fullyOccupied = "true") {
    fullOccupied = "true";
  }
  float percentto = myBuilding1.getOccupancy() * 100;
  float percenttt = myBuilding2.getOccupancy() * 100;

  cout << "Building 1 has " << myBuilding1.getStories() << " floors, "
       << myBuilding1.getApartments() << " apartments, and is " << percentto
       << "% occupied. Full? " << fullOccupied << endl;
  cout << "Building 2 has " << myBuilding2.getStories() << " floors, "
       << myBuilding2.getApartments() << " apartments, and is " << percenttt
       << "% occupied. Full? " << fullOccupied << endl;
  cout << "Looks like people prefer taller buildings." << endl;
}
```

my output matches everything except my boolean values like I said

```
Year 2020: 
Building 1 has 10 floors, 20 apartments, and it 100% occupied. Full? true
Building 2 has 30 floors, 30 apartments, and it 75% occupied. Full? true

Many years pass.

Year 2043: 
Building 1 has 10 floors, 20 apartments, and is 0% occupied. Full? false
Building 2 has 30 floors, 30 apartments, and is 100% occupied. Full? false
Looks like people prefer taller buildings.
```

I have tried changing the bools from being 0 for true and 1 for false, and having the true be "true" and false be "false". I have displayed both in the program so you can see. I am sure you can see I am a beginner in c++ so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Post a minimal example illustrating your problem so we don't need to decipher your scenario.

Comment: myBuilding1.setfullyOccupied(0);
  myBuilding2.setfullyOccupied(1);
  string fullOccupied;
  if (bool fullyOccupied = 1) {
    fullOccupied = "false";
  } else if (bool fullyOccupied = 0) {
    fullOccupied = "true";
  }        Here is the code in question

Comment: It is hard to read.

Comment: @TagUrIT Please don't post code in the comments.  As you can see it's hard to read.  Instead please edit the question to include the code and any additional details.

Comment: What do you think `if (bool fullyOccupied = 1)` does exactly?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I now learn that 1 represents true and 0 represents false I was mistaken and thought it was the other way around. The idea is that when it is completely occupied it will come back as true and if not then false. Depending on the outcome the string will either print true or false. I have fixed the 1 and 0 and have printed the outcome.

Comment: `if (bool fullyOccupied = "false"` is not a bool, it's a char array. `=` is not a comparison.

Comment: Please focus on the part of your code that you are having trouble with. Get rid of everything not necessary "to determine if the building is fully occupied". Isolate the code related to your boolean, as if your output had to be only `Full? true` or `Full? false`. This will make your question more understandable both to the people answering and to the people in the future with the same question.

Comment: @TagUrIT When *what* is completely occupied do you think `if (bool fullyOccupied = 1)` will test as false?

Answer (score 0):

You can print the value of a boolean variable (`true` or `false`) in different ways:

- For example, using `std::boolalpha`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

bool b{false};
std::cout << std::boolalpha << b;  // prints false
```

- Or using the `fmt` library:

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

bool b{false};
fmt::print("{}", b);  // prints false
```

That is, you don't need to convert a boolean into a string in order to print it.

---

A few comments on the code:

- Turning `Building` into a struct, and removing all the getters and setters, would simplify the code a lot. For example, you'd be able to initialize a building like:

```
Building b1{ 10, 20, 1.0};
// Or
Building b2{ .stories = 10, .apartments = 20, .occupancy = 1.0 };
```

- `full` could be changed into a const function that would check the occupancy.
- Repetitive code, like printing out the data of a building, could be separated into a function.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/GYv1roaMo)